# Data with timestamp in format "dd.mm.yyy HH:MM:SS" and plotting

Tags: r, timestamp, axis-labels

I have data with one column of being timestamp in format `dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS`. 
This is how the data looks like:

`> data$TimeStamp
   [1] "14.3.2017 10:00:00" "14.3.2017 10:00:01" "14.3.2017 10:00:02" "14.3.2017 10:00:03" "14.3.2017 10:00:04" "14.3.2017 10:00:05"`

My goal is to produce plots with timestamps on `x-axis` with only time `HH:MM:SS` as labels but the time span may be longer than one day.

So for example my `x-axis` labels could look like this at each tick with one hour intervals:

```
22:00:00     23:00:00     00:00:00     01:00:00     02:00:00
```

I have thought about splitting the character string into date and time and convert time into seconds before plotting but I am willing to hear any alternative paths to do this since I probably will have issues with automatically assigning axis labels properly.

Comment: Hmm what's the question here? Do you want to kinda "strip" your date values like `as.POSIXct(format(df$x, format="1900-01-01 %H:%M:%S"))`?

Comment: I want somehow to be able to plot, for example a temperature of room, versus time. The duration of the measurement could vary from one hour to one week which means I need to be able to have the kind of axis labeling as shown above. I have made one version where I forget about the date part completely and my measurements are always within the same day and on that version I converted my times to seconds.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understood your problem correctly - it's always best to prodive dummy data... See my answer...

Comment: Added an example of raw data.

Comment: Convert them to POSIXct and proceed like in the example. In addition,  [here's how](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/README.html#what-is-a-reprex) to provide example data.

Comment: "Freely choose time interval" is already answered; statistical analysis is a.) another question, b.) very broad and c) prly more suited for stackoverflows' "brother" crossvalidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
df <- data.frame(
  x=Sys.time()+runif(100, 1, 60*60*24*2),
  y=runif(100))
df$x <- as.character(df$x)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: chr  "2017-06-13 18:33:35" "2017-06-14 11:51:49" "2017-06-12 21:51:10" ...
#  $ y: num  0.634 0.738 0.334 0.885 0.461 ...
```

you could define a sort of labeling function

```
f <- function(x) as.POSIXct(levels(cut(x, breaks = "2 hours")))
```

and then do

```
df$x <- as.POSIXct(df$x)
plot(y~x, df, xaxt="n")
with(df, axis(1, at=f(x), labels=format(f(x), "%H:%M:%S")))
```

Comment: So I have to change the format of timestamp in order to use POSIXct.

Comment: `as.POSIXct` converts string to datetime class. `at` specifies tick positions, `labels` specifies tick labels. We want hour-minute-second.